# Which is the parent class for grails domains

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Which class/interface is the parent for all the grails domains.

I just want to know which class actually executes save method of a grails domain

Let us suppose we have grails domain with name book
Book book = new Book("1")
book.save()

There is no save method in book class so where does it actually resides.

Comment: Take a look at https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/api/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormEntity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/api/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormEntity.html

GormEntity is the parent for all domains classes.